# What does it mean to open a directory in vim?

Tags: vim, directory

I did `vim myDirectory`, and got weird output that I don't know how to interpret.

Comment: What output did you get? A directory listing using the netrw plugin?

Comment: @muru yeah something like that

Comment: Post a screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did it look like this?

```
" ============================================================================
" Netrw Directory Listing                                        (netrw v156)
"   /home/Goldname/myDirectory
"   Sorted by      name
"   Sort sequence: [\/]$,\<core\%(\.\d\+\)\=\>,\.h$,\.c$,\.cpp$,\~\=\*$,*,\.o$,\
"   Quick Help: <F1>:help  -:go up dir  D:delete  R:rename  s:sort-by  x:special
" ==============================================================================
../
./
<...list of sub-directories and files within the directory...>
```

That is `vim`'s `netrw` plugin. It lists the contents of the directory, one file or directory per line. You can select a file for editing by moving the cursor onto the line corresponding the file you want and pressing Enter, or switch into another directory by doing the same with the directory you want. Other keys allow various file management operations.

Basically, it's `vim`'s version of a file manager utility.